# resend form data periodically untill connection is back (php)

Tags: php, http, request

i'm new to http requests and php, and i'm trying to find out how to periodically re-send form data in case of internet connection is lost, without losing the form data. any help?
here is how i process the form submit :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test" ) or die("couldn't     connect !") ;

   $a1=$_POST['email'] ;  
   $a2=$_POST['country'] ;  
   ...
   $query="insert into user values ('$a1','$a2','$a3','$a4','$a5','$a6')";
   $exec = mysqli_query($connect ,$query);

   if($exec) 
   {
       echo"<div class='alert alert-success'>
       <strong>data sent !</div>" ; 
   } 
   else
   {   echo"<div class='alert alert-warning'>
       <strong>error occured !</div>" ;
   }
```

Comment: Normally you'd do it with ajax and you'd catch failures and have a way to resubmit.

Comment: you need to do this on the client side, and its normally done with storing the information in local storage until the browser has a connection